# Surface Laptop 3 trackpad won't select text

Tags: touchpad, microsoft-surface

I have 2 laptops, one a Surface Laptop 3 (windows 10) and one a Surface Pro 8 (Windows 11).

My problem is that the Surface laptop track pad does not seem to support selection of text with the track pad.

On my Pro 8 (and every other laptop I can remember), I can press the left side of the track pad onto text to "hold" and then use my right finger to move around the right side of the same track pad to select/highlight text. (The same action as on a mouse - hold left-button and then move the mouse). This doesn't work at all on the Surface Laptop.

I cannot find any specific setting for this (on either machine). It just seems to be normal trackpad behaviour that for some reason is not working.

I have tried updating drivers, re-installing the device, and windows updates.

Is the Surface Laptop 3 trackpad supposed to support this?

It also doesn't "right click" if I press the right side of the track pad, but a double finger tap does trigger a right click. The trackpad doesn't appear to be mechanically broken, it works for generally moving the cursor and left-clicking but not for selecting or right click. If I plug in an external mouse then that works fine, I can select text perfectly.

Comment: If all else fails, you can click at the beginning of the text to select, then Shift-click at the end, to select it all.

Comment: @harrymc - thanks that is a really useful tip, I've never heard of that before.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason the trackpad in your tablet does not select text,
a fallback solution is to :

- Click at the beginning of the text to select
- Shift-click at the end of the text, to select it all.

Comment: This is good advice, but I don't see this as the answer. I would still like to know how to fix the problem. It's also not just selecting that fails. Right click doesn't work the way I would expect either.

Comment: You can't do much except ensure you're using the right driver. What device is the trackpad and what's its driver?

Comment: Device Manager says it's just called "HID-compliant touch pad", Provider: Microsoft, Date:21/06/2006 [strangely old, because the laptop is from 2020]. Driver version: 10.0.19041.2486. Not much to go on. I don't think it is to do with the driver. When I try to update it say "No driver files are required or have been loaded for this device". Directly handled by the OS I assume.

Comment: You could perhaps try first Windows Update. Most drivers seem to also be in [Surface Laptop 3 with Intel Processor Drivers and Firmware](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100429), but installing all of them might be a bit radical.

Comment: Thanks - I have done Windows Update multiple times, as well as specifically attempting to load the latest driver for this device (none is available).

Comment: The components in the above link date from 2018 to 2022, none from 2006.